# select rows where criteria appears more than once sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, where-clause

I have a view on MySQL, and I want to filter out those rows where temID appears more than once for a particular user.

Let's say a sample of the data is:

```
id  name    ques    temID

55  peter   1993    680
55  peter   1994    680
55  peter   1476    680
55  peter   1879    684
55  peter   1440    686
55  peter   1440    686
55  peter   1438    686
55  peter   1921    687
55  peter   1922    687
55  peter   1921    687
56  john    1853    684
56  john    1853    684
56  john    1539    687
56  john    1998    1512
56  john    2281    1534
56  john    2282    1534
56  john    2282    1534
```

I want the results to be

```
id  name    ques    temID

55  peter   1993    680
55  peter   1994    680
55  peter   1476    680
55  peter   1440    686
55  peter   1440    686
55  peter   1438    686
55  peter   1921    687
55  peter   1922    687
55  peter   1921    687
56  john    1853    684
56  john    1853    684
56  john    2281    1534
56  john    2282    1534
56  john    2282    1534
```

These three rows should be removed because the temID only appears once for each user:

```
id  name    ques    temID

55  peter   1879    684
56  john    1539    687
56  john    1998    1512
```

I tried

```
select * from v_tem 
WHERE temID IN
    (     SELECT temID
          FROM v_tem 
          GROUP BY id, temID
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
GROUP BY id, temID
ORDER BY id, temID;
```

but the results are

```
id  name    ques    temID

55  peter   1993    680
55  peter   1994    680
55  peter   1476    680
55  peter   1879    684
55  peter   1440    686
55  peter   1440    686
55  peter   1438    686
55  peter   1921    687
55  peter   1922    687
55  peter   1921    687
56  john    1853    684
56  john    1853    684
56  john    1539    687
56  john    2281    1534
56  john    2282    1534
56  john    2282    1534
```

Only

```
id  name    ques    temID

56  john    1998    1512
```

is removed.

My guess is that because temID 684 appears more than once for john, so it passes the where clause even though it appears only once for peter. Same goes for temID 687. Even though it only appears once for john, because it appears twice for peter, it is not omitted by the where clause.

Please help!

Comment: I know MySQL handles things their own way, but the general GROUP BY rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select o.*
from v_tem o join 
(select id,temID from v_tem group by id,temID having count(1)>1) t
on o.id=t.id and o.temID=t.temID
```

`t` table gives you all the `id-temID` group that occurs more than once.

So join the original table `o` with `t` gives you all the records you need.

sql fiddle here [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b69790/1]

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande added in my answer.Thank you

Comment: Thanks to both @amow and @Ameya!
May I know what count(1) means?

Comment: @jasonC count(1) is the same with count(*), early mysql version doesnt do this optimaze automaticlly.Just a personal habbit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join for correct output. Your inner query return only temId which is duplicate for different users.

Record 55-684 is not being removed because temId 684 is being returned for user 56. Same for other one.

It seems there is no primary key in your table that can be used inside your inner query so you need to use join condition on both id and temId.